# R automate testing?

Tags: arrays, r, automated-tests

Currently, I employ following script to test for something called Granger causality. Note: My main question is about the script structure, not the method.

```
#These values always have to be specified manually
dat <- data.frame(df[2],df[3])
lag = 2

# VAR-Model
V <- VAR(dat,p=lag,type="both")
V$var
summary(V)

wald.test(b=coef(V$var[[1]]), Sigma=vcov(V$var[[1]]), Terms=c(seq(2, by=2, length=lag)))
names(cof1[2])

wald.test(b=coef(V$var[[2]]), Sigma=vcov(V$var[[2]]), Terms=c(seq(1, by=2, length=lag)))
names(cof1[1])
```

Main issue is, that I always manually have to change the testing pair in dat <- data.frame(..). Further, I always manually enter "lag = x" after some tests on stationarity that can rather not be automated.

Let's say I would have to test following pairs:

```
df[2],df[3]
df[2],df[4]
df[2],df[5]
df[6],df[7]
df[8],df[9]
```

can I somehow state that in an array for the test? Assuming I would also know `lag` for each testing pair, could I also add that to it?

It would be perfect to directly output my test results into a table, instead of manually changing the data and then entering the result into an Excel/LaTeX.

Comment: So you want to write a function that inputs the column numbers, and the lag, and outputs your Granger causality.

Comment: Yes, exact. Result should be: (used variable 1) (result from first wald test) (used variable 2) (result from wald test 2) (used lag)

Comment: something like this? `f <- function(x, y) {dat <- data.frame(df[x], df[y]); ...}; Map(f, c(2,2,2,6,8), c(3,4,5,7,9))`

Comment: Is there any example code I could test?